# Get values of checkboxes and parse them corresponding to GSON-model

Tags: android, list, checkbox

I got a large amount (18) of Checkboxes in my Activity and I have to parse their name (if checked) to JSON and send them to the server. 
I got a GSON-model to do the parsing, but how do I get the particular values from the checked Checkboxes and how do I save them to the ArrayList?
Is there any quick way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of views on startup and process those views in cycle- add to response if it is checkef. You can also add checkboxes at runtime to layout in code in case if exact number of check boxes in unknown